# How to Save Image with Custom Name

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using CameraCaptureTask to take a picture and save the resulting image to the Photos Hub. I've noticed that even if I perform no action within the Completed event, a picture is always saved by default to the device's Camera Roll with a standard naming scheme. Is it possible to modify the name before saving? Note I do not want to also save another copy with a custom name via MediaLibrary and have duplicates. If not, is there another way to get the resulting image and save method that would accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `CameraCaptureTask` to save images with custom names. It saves the image to the `CameraRoll` as soon as the image is captured and available.

You can use `PhotoCamera` instead to handle all the required events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx

You can save the image to the `CameraRoll` folder on its `CaptureImageAvailable` event using `MediaLibary`'s `SavePictureToCameraRoll` function. You can optionally save the picture to `Saved Pictures` folder using `MediaLibrary`'s `SavePicture` function.

You can set `flash`, `focus` etc by `overriding` certain functions like `ShutterKeyHalfPressed` , `ShutterKeyPressed`, `ShutterKeyReleased`

So, ideally this class should do everything for you that `CameraCaptureTask` does.

Comment: Is it possible to rename the image as in the answer below from @ZombieSheep?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer, but can't you do something like this (i.e. rename the file when it comes back to you)?

```
void test()
{
    CameraCaptureTask tsk = new CameraCaptureTask();
    tsk.Completed += tsk_Completed;
    tsk.Show();
}

void tsk_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    var fn = e.OriginalFileName;
    File.Move(fn, "newName.jpg");
}
```

*NOTE* Untested